# OR condition in XPath for Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

Currently, I am stuck with the problem in XPath and Scrapy where I have to parse example like this.

```
<dl class>
<x class="another"><a>data 1</a></x>
<y class="y"><b>data 2</b></y>
</dl>
```

I want to fetch the data between  and  tag. So, I was wondering if there is solution like

```
dl=response.xpath(".//dl")
for row in dl.xpath(".//a or .//b")
```

I want to know if I can put the OR condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `|`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr):

```
dl.xpath(".//a | .//b")
```